# Sending POST request (JSON body) to SOAP server returns error

Tags: json, soap, postman

So, we've SOAP server configured at backend and sending POST requests to SOAP endpoint with JSON body and get error like:

**Any solutions or causes please?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <soap:Code>
                <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
            </soap:Code>
            <soap:Reason>
                <soap:Text xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</soap:Text>
            </soap:Reason>
            <soap:Detail />
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: have you checked the message body itself, what are you posting? if it has some unreadable character at the start (called BOM) then this may occur.

Comment: Here's the body `{
 "room_id":"12"
}`